# react native multiple draggable and resizable flatlist

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to create a row column type structure where i can create multiple section which can be dragged as well as resized as per needed, I have used this library(https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-draggable) for making dragable section but how i can configure it to be resizable, also it needs to be limited to the container

```
 <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          flex: 1,
          padding: 20,
        }}>
        <View style={{ flex: 0.3, backgroundColor:'blue' }}>
          <Draggable renderSize={56} renderColor='black' offsetX={-100} offsetY={-200} renderText='A' pressDrag={() => alert('touched!!')} />
        </View>
        <View style={{ flex: 0.3, backgroundColor: 'green' }}>
          <Draggable renderColor='red' renderShape='square' renderText='UC' />
        </View>
        <View style={{ flex: 0.4, backgroundColor: 'yellow' }}>
          <Draggable renderColor='red' renderShape='square' renderText='B' />

          <Draggable />
        </View>
      </View>
```

Comment: have you tried this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-easy-gestures ?

Comment: yes, i have tried this, but it's not showing any content for text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this [Resizable and draggable](http://npmjs.com/package/react-native-easy-gestures) library you can easily achieve this with just 3 lines of code,

```
<Gestures rotatable={false}>
     <Text style={{ padding: 40 }}>AHGHAGS</Text>
</Gestures>
```

see [working example on snack here](https://snack.expo.io/@jdgalani6297/draggable-and-resizable)

Comment: I can go with it, but still a lot more to do with this.. Thank you !